# MoveIt!2 add Pointcloud2 to OccupancyMapMonitor

Tags: ros2, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First my Setup:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS2 Foxy from Debian    Packages
- MoveIt!2 ROS2 UR Driver from https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver
- own Node for Launching RViz with moveIt and the Robot Driver connected to the URSimulator for Linux: all working
- own Node for Receiving a Pointcloud over Network from an RGB-D Camera publishing it as Pointcloud2 in a topic:
  I can see  the Pointcloud in RViz

I would like to use the Pointcloud as "Collision Object" in MoveIt so I tried to use the Perception Pipeline Tutorial from here: https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html
But I can't transfer it from Moveit1 to Moveit2. I tried to find the sensor_manager.launch file or to create it, but got stuck here. Is there another way to give the PointCloud2 the OccupancyMapMonitor?

Thank you for your efforts.

Florian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389233/moveit!2-add-pointcloud2-to-occupancymapmonitor/) by [FlorianSp](https://answers.ros.org/users/87787/floriansp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a hint on this port of the Perception Tutorial (and others) https://github.com/RoboticsYY/moveit_tutorials and found the way to activate the OccupancyMapMonitorUpdater for Pointclouds. Just these Settings in the Launch file:

```
octomap_config = {'octomap_frame': 'camera_rgb_optical_frame', 
                      'octomap_resolution': 0.05,
                      'max_range': 5.0}

octomap_updater_config = load_yaml('avoid_obstacle_scene', 'config/pointcloud_octomap.yaml')
```

And then add the new two parameters to your move_group_node.

---

Originally posted by [FlorianSp](https://answers.ros.org/users/87787/floriansp/) with karma: 46 on 2021-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khairulm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40864/khairulm/) on 2022-09-07**:
can you please show us the content in `pointcloud_octomap.yaml`?

**Comment by [FlorianSp](https://answers.ros.org/users/87787/floriansp/) on 2022-09-07**:
Sorry, I haven't any Access to the project anymore. But I can just remember you can find it very easy by searching online.

**Comment by [ArvindKP](https://answers.ros.org/users/133294/arvindkp/) on 2023-01-04**:
@ FlorianSp
Did you get any specific way/solution for the above mentioned problem?

Thank you